# A python script that prints both USB letter and USB name of a usb device connected on a computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, python-module, pywin32

I am running the python script to print out the usb device letter and name of a USB connected on a computer.
Below is the code.

*

```
import win32api
import win32file
drive_list = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drive_list = drive_list.split("\x00")[0:-1]  
for letter in drive_list:
    if win32file.GetDriveType(letter) == win32file.DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
       print("list of drives connected: {0}".format(letter))
```

Here is the output of the relative script, when a USB device is connected.

*list of drives connected: D:*

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @Kemp I need to see the USB device's name also. FYI i'm only seeing the drive's letter

Answer (score 0):

[`GetLogicalDriveStrings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlogicaldrivestringsw) cannot get the name of the drive, only the string of the drive.

You can use [`GetVolumeInformationW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationw) to get the name of the drive. Here is a sample:

```
import win32api
import win32file
drive_list = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drive_list = drive_list.split("\x00")[0:-1]  

for letter in drive_list:
    if win32file.GetDriveType(letter) == win32file.DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
       print("list of drives connected: {0}".format(letter),end = ' ')
       volname, volsernum, maxfilenamlen, sysflags, filesystemtype = win32api.GetVolumeInformation(letter)
       print(volname)
```

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.